# Класс не найден в PHP

Tags: php, ооп

Пишу свою Mini CRM на ООП, в index.php подключаю класс Router через use, создаю объект этого класса, но мне пишет ошибку Uncaught Error: Class "app\Router" not found, что я делаю не так? [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не вижу соответствующего `require` в Вашем `index.php` файле. Для того чтобы работало через `use`, нужен какой-то автолоадер для автозагрузки классов. Ознакомьтесь с [автоматическая загрузка классов](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.autoload.php) и например с [composer autoloading](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading)

Comment: нет require Router. Остальное есть, а роутера нет

Comment: Ааа... Автолоадер нужен оказывается для use, понял... Спасибо!

Comment: Написал require_once 'app/Router.php';, теперь Uncaught Error: Class "Router" not found

Comment: Всё! Решил! Потом автокомплит в PHPStorm, спасибо всем!