# Class not found

Tags: php, ооп

Не нашёл ответа на свой вопрос, вроде всё делаю правильно, аналогично похожему контроллеру, а все равно PHP выдает ошибку:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "app\controllers\users\HomeController" not found in /var/www/PHP/Mini CRM (Андрей Андриевский)/app/Router.php:18 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/PHP/Mini CRM (Андрей Андриевский)/index.php(15): app\Router->run() #1 {main} thrown in /var/www/PHP/Mini CRM (Андрей Андриевский)/app/Router.php on line 18
> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А где у тебя загрузка классов происходит? `composer.json` что-то я не вижу. и  никаких `require` или `include` тоже

Comment: Также убедись что у тебя `HomeController` имеет правильный `namespace`

Comment: А классы как загружаются? Ты получается пишешь в классе namespace, а в файле где используешь класс пишешь use, не так?

Comment: Namespace точно такой же как и у UsersController, они из одной папки

Comment: Увы, но нет. Не так. .... почитай про composer autoload (автозагрузка)

Comment: Если не composer autoload, то хотя бы про автозагрузку классов с помощью php  spl_autoload_register.  Но сейчас давно все используют композер

Comment: https://webformyself.com/avtozagruzka-klassov-s-composer-v-php/   ............... 
 https://ru.hexlet.io/courses/php-introduction-to-oop/lessons/autoloading/theory_unit

Comment: Вы сюда все время с одними и теми же вопросами ходите. У Вас же был уже подобный вопрос.

Comment: А ведь и правда ........ https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1549996/191482#comment2790622_1549996 ........Работа над ошибками-то не сделана